# what is the best way to change the background image with fade ind and out effect?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

```
     #compareDiv{
    position: fixed; 
    bottom: 0px; 
    right: 220px; 
    background:url(images/compare-V1.png) top left no-repeat; 
    width:80px;
    height:16px; 
    padding:2px 6px;  
    color:#FFF; 
    font-size:12px; 
    font-weight:bold; 
    cursor:pointer;
    }
    #compareDiv:hover{
    background:url(images/compare-V1.png) bottom left no-repeat;
    }
```

this is my code and what i need is change this fast effect with css when it goes normal to hover and give a slow effect change.
any idea?

Comment: well am using jquery  for other animations am doing!

Answer (score 2):

You need to use image tags instead of CSS background property. You can make an image tag act like a background image by setting it's `z-index:0`

**CSS**

```
    body, html{
        margin:0;
        padding:0;
        background:black;
    }
    img{
        position:absolute;
        top:0;
        display:none;
        width:100%;
        height:100%;
    }
```

**HTML**

```
<img src="http://...1.jpg" />
<img src="http://...2.jpg" />
<img src="http://...3.jpg" />
```

**jQuery**

```
function test() {
    $("img").each(function(index) {
        $(this).hide();
        $(this).delay(3000 * index).fadeIn(3000).fadeOut();
    });
}
test();
```

### Check working example at http://jsfiddle.net/RyGKV/

Comment: Agreed — either an image tag, or a second element with the background. There's not a good way to fade JUST the background image out.

Comment: but the question is how can i do the effect if what i want is when it be mouse hover the background change with fade effect?

Answer (score 0):

I made an example for you.

[check it out](http://jsfiddle.net/J4mBL/1/)

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using the css hover effect you can use a combination of JQuery's hover and fadeOut/fadeIn methods to achieve a slower transition with the same effect. However, I noticed you are using the same image but in a different position. This involves a little more work and the best way to achieve this is by also adding and removing classes at the same time during the hover. Something like this could be used for your code:

CSS:

```
.img1 
{    
    background:url(images/compare-V1.png) top left no-repeat;
}

.img2 
{
    background:url(images/compare-V1.png) bottom left no-repeat;
}
```

JQuery:

```
$("#compareDiv").hover(function() {
    $(this).fadeOut('slow', function() {
        $(this).removeClass('img1').addClass('img2').fadeIn('slow');
    });
}, function() {
    $(this).fadeOut('slow', function() {
        $(this).removeClass('img2').addClass('img1').fadeIn('slow');
    });
});
```

I set up an example in this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/gZQtm/